# Boost.Asio deadline_timer not working as expected

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to implement a timeout for a Boost.Asio read on a TCP socket.

I am trying to use a `async_read_some` with a `deadline_timer`. My function below is a member of a class that holds a smart pointer to the TCP socket and `io_service`. What I would **expect** to happen when called on an active socket that doesn't return any data is **wait 2 seconds and return false**.

What happens is: If the socket never returns any data it works as expected. How ever if the server returns the data the proceeding calls to the method below return immediately because to timers callback is called without waiting the two seconds.

I tried commenting out the `async_read_some` call and the function always works as expected. Why would `async_read_some` change how the timer works?

```
    client::client() {
        // Init socket and timer
        pSock = boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket > (new tcp::socket(io_service));
    }

bool client::getData() {

              // Reset io_service
                io_service.reset(); 

                // Init read timer
                boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(pSock->io_service());
                timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(2)); 
                timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&client::read_timeout, this, boost::system::error_code(), true));


    //            // Async read the data
                pSock->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer_),
                        boost::bind(&client::read_complete,
                        this,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
                        ));



                // While io_service runs check read result 
                while (pSock->io_service().run_one()) {
                    if (m_read_result > 0) {
                        // Read success 
                        return m_read_result;
                    }else if(m_read_result < 0){
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
}



void client::read_complete(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred) {
    if (!error) {
        m_read_result = bytes_transferred;
    }else{
        m_read_result = -1;
    }
}

void client::read_timeout(const boost::system::error_code& error, bool timeout) {
    if(!error){
        m_read_result = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the complete (and it would be good if minimal) source code? My previous answer was unfortunately wrong.

Comment: Added async handler code

Comment: You set in `read_complete` result to `bytes_transfered` when it is an error, and `-1` when there is no error. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, I was suggested by your code. Remove `!` from `!error`. That is one error. The another is, that when you receive any data, you return from function and this causes calling the destructor of deadline_timer, which should call callback with error "operation_aborted".

Comment: I don't believe either are errors, calling if(!error){//no error}else{//error} is correct, is see it all through the examples of boost. Also I am not leaving the function calling a function within a function should never call the deconstructor of a local object.

Comment: You return from function `getData`. Also the conditions on both callbacks contradict themselves - therefore one of them is an error.

Comment: read_timeout was misleading. I edited the above code. When do I return? The only place I return is in the while loop or if it breaks from the while loop, the later is not the case. The read_timeout is called before returning from the getData when I test it.

Comment: How do you test that read_timeout is called before returning from `getData`? Destructors will be called before returning to the calling function. Please, change `if(!error)` to `if(error)` and try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple problem when setting up the timer  boost::system::error_code() should be changed to _1 or a error::placeholder

```
timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&client::read_timeout, this, _1, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have negated condition when you check for connection errors.

It should be:

```
if(error){
    std::cout  << "read_timeout Error - " << error.message() << std::endl;
}
```

Now you will see, that the callback is invoked with error code `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`.

This is because, when you receive any data, you return from function `getData` and `deadline_timer`'s destructor calls the callback with the error code set.

Comment: I do check error codes in my timeout handler, they are always called with success.

Comment: I edited the code, same issue.  deadline_timer is not being constructed until after I already received the premature fire of the timeout.